# Sending sms from background in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

hello friends i wanted to send SMS to another mobile using windows phone app but this Task of sending SMS should happen in background.
so is it possible if yes the which API should i target to achieve this goal.
any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the background? Meaning: without the user knowing it? No, that's not possible. Unless you get priviliges from the mobible network provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br206567

Comment: thanks venerik..is it possible to send sms silently but when sms delivered user got notification..like without opening native sms sending application on windows phone ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you will need special priviliges for this as well.

Comment: You can't do a thing without user "touch"